Was Nedry in the Dilophosaurus paddock or had they also escaped?
In Jurassic Park, Dennis Nedry is killed by a Dilophosaurus in his jeep at the top of a waterfall.
At the bottom of the waterfall is a road that goes into a tunnel with a sign for the East Dock.
Is the waterfall in the Dilophosaurus paddock or have the Dilophosaurus escaped their paddock?

I believe we know, from the displayed images, that all of the security fences except for the raptors were turned off, so those dinos had an opportunity to escape. I haven't found anything official for where the waterfall is, and at least one fan claims that the geography doesn't work out.

Nedry's route is kept somewhat opaque by the film, which means that we don't actually know where he was attacked and where he died.
We do know that he intended to head to the East Dock and got turned around, so it's likely he ended up driving on the road that runs alongside the dilophosaurus enclosure. The prop map shows a small creek crossing the road. Possibly this is where he accidentally drove off the embankment and ended up alongside or inside the paddock, where he then encountered the dinosaurs.

That all being said, whether he was inside or outside the enclosure is a completely moot point as the electric fences were down and the dinos were totally free to roam the entire park. The 'enclosure' was no longer enclosing anything.
